# Add a new row with a select field as a cell

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-tsx, mui-x-data-grid

I am using DataGrid from the MUI library. I have a table with four cells (id: number, processPath: SelectField, associateLogin: TextFields, action: Button). I have also added functionality to add and remove rows on button click. The issue I am facing is with the column called processPath, the cell take a SelectField, updates the value, but each time I add a new row, it's holding onto to the previous rows value. The reason I have chosen to include the other columns is because I would like the person answering the question to have the full scope, and the reason for my data-structure. My issue from a glance is that I have a UDF Function Component that I am reusing on handleAddRow, but I do not know how to update the next rows state to be blank.

```
import {
  FormControl,
  InputLabel,
  MenuItem,
  Select,
  SelectChangeEvent,
  Box,
  Button,
  Stack,
} from "@mui/material";
import {
  DataGrid,
} from "@mui/x-data-grid";
import React, { FunctionComponent, useState } from "react";

const processPaths: string[] = ["Test1", "Test2"];

export const AccomodationsTable: FunctionComponent = () => {
  const [idCounter, setIdCounter] = useState(0);
  const [rowCounter, setRowCounter] = useState(0);

  const [formData, setFormData] = useState([
    {
      id: idCounter,
      processPath: "",
      associateLogin: "",
      action: "",
    },
  ]);

  const ProcessPathSelectField: FunctionComponent = () => {
    function handleChange(event: SelectChangeEvent) {
      const { name, value } = event.target;
      setFormData((prevFormData) => ({
        ...prevFormData,
        [name]: value,
      }));
    }

    return (
      <Box>
        <FormControl fullWidth>
          <InputLabel id={`process-path-select-${idCounter}`}>
            Please Select
          </InputLabel>
          <Select
            labelId="process-path-select"
            id={`process-path-select-${idCounter}`}
            value={formData[0].processPath}
            name="processPath"
            label={`process-path-select-${idCounter}`}
            onChange={handleChange}
            sx={{ minWidth: "240px" }}
          >
            {processPaths.sort().map((processPath) => (
              <MenuItem value={processPath}>{processPath}</MenuItem>
            ))}
          </Select>
        </FormControl>
      </Box>
    );
  };

  const createNewRow = () => {
    setIdCounter((prevIdCounter) => (prevIdCounter + 1));
    return {
      id: idCounter,
      processPath: "",
      associateLogin: "",
      action: "",
    };
  };

  const [rows, setRows] = useState(() => [createNewRow()]);

  const handleAddRow = () => {
    setRows((prevRows) => [...prevRows, createNewRow()]);
  };

  const handleRemoveRow = () => {
    setRows(rows.slice(0, idCounter - 1));
    setIdCounter((prevIdCounter) => (prevIdCounter - 1));
  };

  const columns = [
    { field: "id" },
    {
      field: "Process Path",
      width: 270,
      renderCell: () => <ProcessPathSelectField />,
    },
    { field: "Associate Login", width: 270 },
    { field: "Action", width: 270 },
  ];

  return (
    <>
      <Box sx={{ width: "100%" }}>
        <Stack direction="row" spacing={1} sx={{ mb: 1 }}>
          <Button size="small" onClick={handleRemoveRow}>
            Remove a row
          </Button>
          <Button size="small" onClick={handleAddRow}>
            Add a row
          </Button>
        </Stack>
        <Box sx={{ height: 400, mt: 1 }}>
          <DataGrid
            rows={rows}
            columns={columns}
            columnVisibilityModel={{
              id: false,
            }}
          />
        </Box>
      </Box>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Sorry, one to thing mention is that prior to the code above I was simply setting the state of processPath, not using formData.